# How to use a method with an object which could be extended with different class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I've got a main class and two inherited class:

```
public class mother{
    public String Melement;
}
```

and

```
public class boy extends mother {
    public String Belement;
}
```

and

```
public class girl extends mother{
    public String Gelement;
}
```

So I could have an object A like `boy A = new boy();`
and an object B like `girl B = new girl();`

And I would like to use a method with these objects, but it doesn't work

This is what I tried:

```
public void mymethod(mother MyObject) {
    if (MyObject instanceof boy){
        String A = MyObject.Melement;
        String B = MyObject.Belement;
    }

    if (MyObject instanceof girl){
        String A = MyObject.Melement;
        String B = MyObject.Gelement;
    }
}
```

I understand that it's not working because `Myobject` is of type `mother` so I could access only `Melement`
But I would like my method to accept the both type of objects `boy` and `girl`

Is it possible to do it? How?

Comment: [Cast it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

Comment: [You should follow java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it the check of `instance of` does work, you still need to cast it to a Boy class in order to work. Simply do `String B = ( (boy) MyObject ).Belement;`